# what the difference between the typedef

Tags: c

what the difference if I wroth like this 
the tree code I describe

```
typedef struct LNode
{
void* data;
struct LNode* next;
}LNode;
```

or

```
typedef struct Node
{
void* data;
struct Node* next;
}LNode;
```

or

```
typedef struct
{
void* data;
}LNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

The 1st creates a structure named LNode and a typedef to LNode as LNode

The 2nd creates a structure named Node and a typedef to Node as LNode

The 3rd one just typedef a struct to LNode